# How to use JSON data from wcf url in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, wcf

I am trying to receive the JSON data from the WCF service url in javascript.

I used the following javascript code.

```
$(function(){
$("input:button").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://192.168.1.109/EIM/EIS.svc/json/getLatestLocation/Mobile/Mobile/1001",
      success: function (data) {
          var innerHtml = "";
          document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=data;
                 //'test' is ID of <div>
          document.getElementById('testlab').innerHTML=data.getLatestLocationResult.status.code;
                //'testlab' is ID of <label>
          $("#test").html(innerHtml);
          alert("JSON DATA");
          alert(data.getLatestLocationResult.status.code);
          }
        });
    });
 });
```

JSON data from url is:

```
 {"getLatestLocationResult":{"status":{"code":"00","description":"Request
 OK"},"reason":{"code":"000","description":"Request
 OK"},"PersonDetails":{"PersonName":"Santosh Kumar
 Sahu","PersonNumber":"1001","Identification":"Pan
 Card","IdentificationNumber":"P567","ContactNo":"987654","Gender":"Male"},"location":[{"dateandtime":"7\/17\/2013
 10:45:20   AM","latitude":"19.0469536","longitude":"72.9112502","address":"ND","city":"ND","state":"ND","country":"ND"}]}}
```

Please give me a suggestion to use receive this data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should `eval` the data - otherwise it's just a string.

```
obj = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

Now you can use `obj` as a rightful JS object and access it's members.
Here is the fiddle which evaluates your `data` string and accesses the resulting object members http://jsfiddle.net/M4BK5/

Comment: can you brief how to use obj.

Comment: `obj.getLatestLocationResult.status.code` should be "00" for example. `json` is just a string. If you want to make a JS object out of it, you have to `eval` that string.

Comment: Yes I tried with that.. still nothing is happening on clicking the button.

Comment: And it doesn't send the AJAX request? Try wrapping your function with `document.ready` - seems to me that you are trying to assign event handler before button is rendered on the page.

Comment: thank you @ElmoVanKielmo. I understood your suggestion, now the thing is code inside $ajax is not working. Tried and confirmed using alert box.